# Creating a directory from multiple threads

Tags: php

If multiple threads do the following:

```
if ( !is_dir($dir) )
    mkdir($dir, 0, true);
```

what will happen if two threads will detect "at the same time" that the directory does not exist and then they both try and create it?

Is `mkdir` synchronized to prevent bad things from happening or is there a way to `flock` this to make sure that only one thread creates the directory and/or files ?

Comment: Do you convert your php warnings into exceptions? The other options I could see are: `@` (oh god, I cannot believe I propose it) or some custom synchronization point with `flock`

Comment: Your method that detect the missing of directory must be synchronize in this way that just one thread to execute that. A related question what is show that flock is synchronized is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185203/php-5-x-syncronized-file-access-no-database that you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only one of them will manage to create the directory, the other `mkdir` will return `false` and throw a warning

You can also have a look at this [bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=35326) in php, it's not exactly the case like with your question, but it is related

Comment: The other would also throw a warning

Comment: So ... how is it ? :) zerkms, you 100% sure that this would happen? If so, what would the solution be then?

Comment: @zerkms yes, it will throw a warning, thanks, I added it to my answer. @AndreiBogdan, it will still work, but if you want to get rid of the warning, you can suppress it with `@` as @zerkms suggested

Answer (score 3):

I know this an old question but something like this works really well, assuming you have an error handler that converts errors to exceptions (which is a good idea anyway):

```
    /**
     * Create a folder in a thread safe way
     * Between 'is_dir' and 'mkdir' another thread could have created a folder. 
     * This can cause the system to raise an unwarrented error
     * 
     * Returns TRUE if folder was created, NULL if folder already exists
     * 
     * Throws exception on any other error
     *
     * @param  array   $array
     * @param  string  $key
     * @param  mixed   $value
     * @return array
     */
    function mkdir_thread_safe($dir, $permissions = 0777, $recursive = false)
    {   
        if(is_dir($dir)) return;

        try {
             mkdir($dir, $permissions, $recursive);
        }
        catch (\ErrorException $e){

            if(is_dir($dir)) return;

            throw $e;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Here is the error to exception conversion handler - this is really good practice anyway, and should be added at the start of any application entry point. Some modern frameworks such as laravel, take care of this by default, so if you are using laravel, your errors will already be converted to exceptions.

```
set_error_handler(function ($level, $message, $file, $line, $context)
{
    if (error_reporting() & $level)
    {
        throw new ErrorException($message, $level, 0, $file, $line);
    }
});
```